# VS2015 + VTK 7.1.0 + Qt 5.8.0 running Qt examples from VTK entry point failure

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2015, vtk, qvtkwidget

Currently I am trying to use the VTK library in combination with Qt to build an application to visualize STL-files. To get started I installed the following libraries/programs:

- Visual Studio 2015 Professional
- CMake 3.7.0
- VTK 7.1.0
- Qt 5.8.0

For Qt I used the version which is compiled for vs2015 namely:

- qt-opensource-windows-x86-msvc2015_64-5.8.0.exe

After following the instructions provided by [Kitware](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Configure_and_Build) everything seems to be fine, I didn't got any errors while configuring and building VTK. So then I decided to use some example code of VTK as a starting point.

Again the linking and building of the application went well but as soon as I tried to start the application I received the following error:

**The procedure entry point ?rgbSwapped@QImage@@QEHAA$$QEAV1@Z could not be located in the dynamic link library C:\VTK\bin\bin\Release\vtkGUISupportQt-7.1.dll.**

I have searched for a solution but I cannot find one. I also tried other versions of VTK and Qt but I still get this error. For example this morning I tried VTK 6.3.0 in combination with Qt 4.8.5, again everthing went well untill I tried to run some code this time I received this error:

**The procedure entry point ?doItemsLayout@QTableView@@UAEXXZ could not be located in the dynamic link library C:\VTK\bin\bin\Release\vtkGUISupportQt-6.3.dll.**

If somebody has experience with this kind of errors please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. It seems strange to me, why system doesn`t see QT dll in the $PATH, but if you put Qt dll in you executable directory it will run fine. maybe someone with more expirence can explain this behavior.

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem. I thought the error was caused by the .dll files from VTK but apparently I was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

> It seems strange to me, why system doesn`t see QT dll in the $PATH,
>   but if you put Qt dll in you executable directory it will run fine.

It depends on how DLLs are found by Windows. See [Dynamic-Link Library Search Order](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586(v=vs.85).aspx) for details. For that reason, I always put the required DLLs in the executable directory so that the correct version of DLLs are used. It is good to have a list of required DLLs as those DLLs will also need to be shipped to the end users.